# EC2 no space left, can't find out what's using the space

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a small ec2 instance (Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)) as a jenkins node. It just greeted me with "no space left". `ssh` into it and `df -h` shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G   44M  3.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  560K  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1       64G   63G  1.5G  98% /
tmpfs           798M     0  798M   0% /run/user/1000
```

As shown the usage of `/dev/xvda1` is 98% (I just cleaned up tmp and cache).

But I can't find out what's consuming the space.

`du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr` from `/` shows:

```
...error messages of Permission denied
3.5G    .
1.4G    ./usr
1.2G    ./home
588M    ./var
200M    ./opt
57M ./tmp
40M ./boot
18M ./etc
552K    ./run
0   ./sys
0   ./srv
0   ./root
0   ./proc
0   ./mnt
0   ./media
0   ./local
0   ./dev
```

If I append `sudo` in front of it I get error like `du: cannot access ‘./proc/24384/task/24384/fd/3’: No such file or directory`

From what I've done, there seems nothing huge consuming my 64GB disk space.

What have I missed?

Comment: You command is for Max depth 1. Can you try 2 or check the /var/log first. Generally that's one place where lot of logs do get generated. Your /tmp seems to be fine.

Comment: If you manage to get enough space to install `ncdu`, try `sudo ncdu /`.

Comment: @AmitavRoy Hi, max-depth=2 returns same total size (3.5G). `/var/log` is part of `./var` right? It's only 588M.

Comment: @Amadan `ncdu` returns same result - ran from `/`, says total disk usage is 3.5G

Comment: Then maybe you have some huge deleted files that are being held on to by a process, or something like that. Does a reboot help?

Comment: Following Amadan's comment, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141639/56646

Comment: If possible, Can you try restarting your server or application running on it? Maybe some stale process holding on to disk space.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.

Answer (score 2):

To find large files on the system we can use the 'find' command along with the -size parameter.

```
sudo find / -type f -size +1M -exec ls -lah {} \;
```

Change the +1M in the above example to meet your requirements. The example will find all files from the file system's root (and deeper), of type file, and larger than 1MB in size.

Example of output:

```
user@server:~$ sudo find / -type f -size +1M -exec ls -lah {} \;
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 3.4M Oct 17  2018 /root/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha1/a5/67/c2af000ad22dc8f2a653d91978ae1f5316f4
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 8.6M Jul 10 16:21 /lib/udev/hwdb.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.6M Jan 28  2018 /lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-OUI.hwdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M Jan 28  2018 /lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-usb-vendor-model.hwdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.8M Jan 28  2018 /lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-pci-vendor-model.hwdb
[... output suppressed ...]
```

It's of course very possible that the problem is a large number of small files taking up all the disk space. You'll have to analyse the output of the find command.

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem. Long story short, is docker's overlay data accumulating.

[more information](https://forums.docker.com/t/some-way-to-clean-up-identify-contents-of-var-lib-docker-overlay/30604)

Because those filese are recognized as open files somehow, it's not showing as a result of `du` or `ncdu`. They can be viewed with `lsof`. Note they have "deleted" markers after them though.

`docker system prune -f -a --filter "until=72h"` reclaimed 50GB for me.